# I've installed discord.py using pip, but after trying to import it into my program, it says that it isn't found?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

Trying to make a bot.
Here's the code that I tried to use to import it:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

And here is the error message that comes up. (I've also installed dotenv just for reference using pip too.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rhiam/Desktop/pufflebot/bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: The problem might be with your folder and file names, if your folder is named `discord`, it'll conflict with the module.

Comment: Hmm, no none of my folders or files to do with the bot are named discord. But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling `discord.py`:

```
pip uninstall discord.py
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

If that doesn't work, it might be an issue with the python version. Others have stated that it works for python version 3.6, but not for 3.8.

Comment: that's weird I'm hosting on repl.it and use python 3.8

Comment: Indeed, there might have been a fix though. Btw, I would recommend installing a local ide. It's easier to manage packages that way

Comment: I cant host 24/7 on a local ide, if I could I would.